# Using Regex with Rasa (How to recognize entities not in training examples)

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, nlu

I am working on a customer relations chatbot. The user can input a greeting, user name, phone number etc.,

I created a few training examples(50+ names) to help the chatbot in nlu.md file. But the problem is the chatbot is not able to recognize an user_name as an entity if it is not specified in the training data (nlu.md) file.

I wrote a regex as well but still if I give a new name the nlu engine is not able to recognise it.

I’m using rasa 1.0.7 and I have pipeline: supervised_embeddings

for example

**nlu.md file:**

```
##regex.names
- [a-zA-Z\s]+$


##intent:inform
- John
- Roshan
- Sanvi
–> have few more
```

If User is giving any new names means, my entity is empty. attaching the **rasa interactive** message also.

Your input -> John

Is the intent ‘inform’ correct for [John] (name) and are all entities labeled correctly? (Y/n)

Your input -> adrena

Your NLU model classified ‘adrena’ with intent ‘inform’ and there are no entities, is this correct? (Y/n )

What should I do to make the bot understand when a user_name is specified? I saw somewhere that lookup tables can be used. But when I tried using lookup tables, it still did not recognize user_name not part of the training examples.

The below links I referred.

https://forum.rasa.com/t/regex-entity-names/11739/10

[How rasa_nlu using lookup_tables for entity extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084656/how-rasa-nlu-using-lookup-tables-for-entity-extraction)

but no luck for my issue. I am okay with any options also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `SpaCyEntityExtractor` with the dimension `PERSON` instead of `CRFEntityExtractor` for that specific entity.  For personal name recognition this will almost always give you better results since there are so many name possibilities. AFAIK the `PERSON` SpaCy model is itself case sensitive. You can still extract other custom entities with `CRFEntityExtractor`. In your pipeline this would look like:

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
- name: "RegexFeaturizer"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
- name: "CountVectorsFeaturizer"
- name: "EmbeddingIntentClassifier"
- name: "SpacyNLP"
  model: "en_core_web_md"
- name: "SpacyEntityExtractor"
  dimensions: ["PERSON"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but maybe useful for other people, using RASA 2:

I'd try to:

1. configuring custom entity `name` as a RASA lookup table,
2. supplying examples in a dedicated intent `name` containing sentences containing the entity in object:

```yaml
version: "2.0"

nlu:

  - lookup: name
    examples: |
      - John
      - Roshan
      - Sanvi
      - Anita
      - Anna
      # many others names (hundreds)

  - intent: name
    examples: |
      - [John](name)
      - call me [Roshan](name)
      - [Sanvi](name) is my name
      - my name is [Paola](name)
      - I'm [Annabelle](name)
      # etc etc.
```

See a similar issue solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793356/1786393

> BTW, @Melina solution using Spacy `PERSON` predefined entity is also a probable good solution (for names that belong to the single selected Spacy language model) that's probably cooperating with the custom entity/intent solution, just naming the custom intent `PERSON` (to be verified/I'm not sure).